# Scrape web with info from several years and create a csv file for each year

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, filenames

I have scraped information with the results of the 2016 Chess Olympiad, using the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

#Imports the HTML into python
url = 'https://www.olimpbase.org/2016/2016te14.html'
requests.get(url)
page = requests.get(url)
print(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

#Subsets the HTML to only get the HTML of our table needed
table = soup.find('table', attrs = {'border': '1'})
print(table)

#Gets all the column headers of our table, but just for the first eleven columns in the webpage
table.find_all('td', class_= 'bog')[1:12]
headers = []
for i in table.find_all('td', class_= 'bog')[1:12]:
    title = i.text.strip()
    headers.append(title)

#Creates a dataframe using the column headers from our table
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)

table.find_all('tr')[3:] #We grab data since the fourth row; the previous ones belong to the headers.

for j in table.find_all('tr')[3:]:
    row_data = j.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text for tr in row_data][0:11]
    length = len(df)
    df.loc[length] = row
```

I want to do the same thing for the results of 2014 and 2012 (the Olympics are played every two years normally), authomatically. I have advanced the code half the way, but I really don't know how to continue. This is what I've done so far.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

#Imports the HTML into python
url = 'https://www.olimpbase.org/2016/2016te14.html'
requests.get(url)
page = requests.get(url)
print(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

#Subsets the HTML to only get the HTML of our table needed
table = soup.find('table', attrs = {'border': '1'})
print(table)

#Gets all the column headers of our table
table.find_all('td', class_= 'bog')[1:12]
headers = []
for i in table.find_all('td', class_= 'bog')[1:12]:
    title = i.text.strip()
    headers.append(title)

#Creates a dataframe using the column headers from our table
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)

table.find_all('tr')[3:] #We grab data since the fourth row; the previous ones belong to the headers. 

start_year=2012
i=2
end_year=2016 

def download_chess(start_year):
    url = f'https://www.olimpbase.org/{start_year}/{start_year}te14.html'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    for j in table.find_all('tr')[3:]:
        row_data = j.find_all('td')
        row = [tr.text for tr in row_data][0:11]
        length = len(df)
        df.loc[length] = row

while start_year<end_year:
    download_chess(start_year)
    start_year+=i    

download_chess(start_year)
```

I don't have much experience so I don't quite understand the logic of writing filenames. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will retrieve information for a range of years - in this case, 2000 -- 2018, and save each table to csv as well:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

years = range(2000, 2019, 2)

for y in years:
    try:
        df = pd.read_html(f'https://www.olimpbase.org/{y}/{y}te14.html')[1]
        new_header = df.iloc[2]
        df = df[3:]
        df.columns = new_header
        print(df)
        df.to_csv(f'chess_olympics_{y}.csv')
    except Exception as e:
        print(y, 'error', e)
```

This will print out the results table for each year:

|  | no. | team | Elo | flag | code | pos. | pts | Buch | MP | gms | nan | + | = | - | nan | + | = | - | nan | % | Eloav | Elop | ind.medals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | Russia | 2685 | nan | RUS | 1 | 38 | 457.5 | 20 | 56 | nan | 8 | 4 | 2 | nan | 23 | 30 | 3 | nan | 67.9 | 2561 | 2694 | 1 - 0 - 2 |
| 4 | 2 | Germany | 2604 | nan | GER | 2 | 37 | 455.5 | 22 | 56 | nan | 10 | 2 | 2 | nan | 21 | 32 | 3 | nan | 66.1 | 2568 | 2685 | 0 - 0 - 2 |
| 5 | 3 | Ukraine | 2638 | nan | UKR | 3 | 35½ | 457.5 | 21 | 56 | nan | 8 | 5 | 1 | nan | 18 | 35 | 3 | nan | 63.4 | 2558 | 2653 | 1 - 0 - 0 |
| 6 | 4 | Hungary | 2661 | nan | HUN | 4 | 35½ | 455.5 | 21 | 56 | nan | 8 | 5 | 1 | nan | 22 | 27 | 7 | nan | 63.4 | 2570 | 2665 | 0 - 0 - 0 |
| 7 | 5 | Israel | 2652 | nan | ISR | 5 | 34½ | 463.5 | 20 | 56 | nan | 7 | 6 | 1 | nan | 17 | 35 | 4 | nan | 61.6 | 2562 | 2649 | 0 - 0 - 0 |

[...]

Relevant documentation for pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html